# Use custom directory for "templatetags"

Tags: django, django-1.7

some one know if its likely use custom directory for "templatetags" eje: "my-project/templatetags"

```
Normal
My-Project-Name
  My-App
    __init__.py
      templatetags
        __init__.py
```

Need Some Like This

```
My-Project-Name
  templatetags
    __init__.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The reason being, `templatetags` *must* reside inside a django app.

From the [documentation of `templatetags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout):

> Custom template tags and filters must live inside a Django app. If
>   they relate to an existing app it makes sense to bundle them there;
>   otherwise, you should create a new app to hold them.
>
> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as
>   models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it -
>   don’t forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated
>   as a Python package. After adding this module, you will need to
>   restart your server before you can use the tags or filters in
>   templates.

Comment: but Django application shows that it can be used in the root of the project, django/templatetags/cache.py, and tried add templatetags, in INSTALLED_APPS..

Comment: It is not at the root level. It is at `django/django/templatetags/` which is an `app` - See the source: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/templatetags

Answer (score 13):

This is possible. Just add location of your `templatetags.py` or templatetags directory to Django `settings.py` into [`OPTIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates) in TEMPLATES setting.

In my case I put my templatetags in the `libs/` directory that is located in project root dir.
You have two options, `builtins` or `libraries`:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        ...
        'builtins': [
            'libs.templatetags'
        ],
        # or as @x-yuri pointed out, you can put them in `libraries`
        'libraries': {
            'my_tags': 'libs.templatetags',
        },
    }
}]
```

If you use `builtins`, it is available everywhere and you don't need to use `{% load %}` for that.
If you use `libraries` you need to use `{% load my_tags %}`.

Comment: There's also [`libraries`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) option for those to be loaded on demand.